# Interpreting Error Code -102 Nightmare.js Scraping

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

I'm just getting started with Nightmare.js. I'm building off of their demo, which targeted duckduckgo.com and worked beautifully. I set my sights on imdb.com and got . . .

```
{ message: 'navigation error',
  code: -102,
  details: 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED',
  url: 'https://imdb.com/' }
```

My questions are 1) whether or not this came up because imdb.com knew it was being scraped or some other reason and 2) is it a Nightmare thing, a Node.js thing, or an Electron thing? I've tried googling about for the specific code and gotten very nonspecific answers. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url: 'https://imdb.com/'`
Make it just 
`url: 'http://imdb.com/'`
If you try navigating to https://imdb.com in any other browser you get redirected to http://imdb.com. It seems they don't provide https: on their homepage. Changing the code to use the http version made it work for me.